# Bounding data in matlab

Tags: matlab, bounding

[Demo data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXEKL.png)

Data set can be found here :
[Dataset](https://justpaste.it/1ds54)
Each point (x;y) indicated the value (y) of the xth sample measured

I am trying to bound a data region which has the most data points just like in the figure , by using 2 line y=a and y=b
How can i approach this solution

Comment: If my answer helped you in solving your problem, please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your minimum and maximum for y values are respectively 960 and 972:

```
y(y < 960) = 960;
y(y > 972) = 972;
```

Alternatively, you can remove those outliers instead of bounding them:

```
y_idx = find((y < 960) | (y > 972));
x(y_idx) = [];
y(y_idx) = [];
```

Comment: There are various extreme high peaks / low peaks in the data.If using this method , all datas that are <max and >min  will be loss?

Comment: With the first method, the data is not lost, only modified to stay above your minimum and below your maximum. With the second approach you remove the peak observations.